# adding special characters and merge the values in a dataframe R

Tags: r

Is is possible to add special characters and paste multiple columns in to a single column

For instance

```
col1 col2 col3
1.01 0.98 1.23
```

TO

```
final_col
1.01(0.98-1.23)
```

I am aware of the paste function with "sep" option to add characters between column, 
paste(col2, col3, sep ="-")

but I am stuck with adding the brackets and can it be done altogether.

Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 do.call(sprintf, c(df1, fmt='%g(%g-%g)'))
 #[1] "1.01(0.98-1.23)" "0.2(1.3-1.2)"
```

Or

```
 with(df1, paste0(col1,'(', col2, '-', col3, ')'))
 #[1] "1.01(0.98-1.23)" "0.2(1.3-1.2)"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c(1.01,0.2), col2=c(0.98, 1.3), 
                     col3=c(1.23, 1.2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option :

```
paste0(dx[,1],'(',paste0(dx[,-1],collapse='-'),')')
## [1] "1.01(0.98-1.23)"
```